# Java multi threaded counter is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, integer

I am trying Java multi threaded counter. I first tried without any synchronisation to observe the race condition. But my counter is not incremented by worker threads.

**Code - MAIN METHOD**

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    System.out.println("Program started");
    Integer sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Initial Sum : " + sum);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(sum, i);
        workerThread.run();
    }

    System.out.println("Final Sum : " + sum);

}
```

**Code - WorkerThread class**

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private Integer localSum;


    public WorkerThread(Integer sum, int i){
        localSum = sum;
        System.out.println(localSum);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        localSum += 1;
    }
}
```

I wonder why incrementing `localSum` does not affect to Integer wrapper object `sum`.
The `sum` value stays at 0. Can anyone help me to figure out how to pass Integer wrapper into a thread and increment the original value?

Comment: Change `sum` to `AtomicInteger`

Comment: "... is not working" Is not a question. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: FYI, your program does not create any new threads. The most basic way to create a new thread in a Java program is to create a new `java.lang.Thread` instance, `t`, and then call `t.start()`. Other ways of creating threads (e.g., by using a `ThreadPoolExector` instance) are basically library wrappers around the same underlying mechanism.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I just wanna see the race condition at the moment. Not to fix them.

Comment: @Welgriv My counter is not incremented by threads. It stays at 0.

Comment: Style advice: You probably should not put "Thread" in the name of a thing that is not a thread. An instance of your `WorkerThread` class is not a thread. A better name for it might be `WorkerTask`, since it's `run()` is the code for a task that you want your program to perform.

Comment: You `sum` variable is not being incremented because `Integer` does not hold a pointer-like reference, so when you do `localSum = sum; localSum++;` it will not increment `sum` automatically, as @MuratKaragöz said, you should probably use `AtomicInteger`, since it will hold a pointer-like reference

Comment: @HenriqueSabino Integer is a wrapper. It is an object and a reference should be pased.. As run  is not called in a new thread it also runs in the same context synchron. I rather think unboxing and boxing.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `localSum += 1` does not do what you think it does.

`Integer` objects are immutable: You can not change the value of an `Integer`.  The `localSum+=1` statement creates a *new* `Integer` instance, and it changes the `localSum` variable to refer to the new instance.  Meanwhile, the `main()` routine's `sum` variable always will refer to the original, immutable instance.

@Murat Karagöz said, "Use an `AtomicInteger`." That would solve *two* problems;

1. [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instances *are* mutable, and
2. The `ai.incrementAndGet()` operation, and other `AtomicInteger` operations are *thread safe*.

Your program, as written, doesn't need thread safety, but it *will* need once you change it to actually create multiple threads.

It will help you to get it right if you make all of your `AtomicInteger` variables `final`. E.g.;

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicInteger localSum;

    public WorkerThread(AtomicInteger sum, int i){
        localSum = sum;
        System.out.println(localSum.get());
    }
    ...
}
```

You don't want to accidentally change the value of the `localSum` field (i.e., you don't want to change which `AtomicInteger` instance it points to,) You want to *mutate* the `AtomicInteger` instance itself.

Comment: By using AtomicInteger I could simulate the race condition. I changed `workerThread` to extend Thread class and instantiated `Thread` type workerThread and started it. It worked.I passed localSum object to into Synchronized() block in run method of workerThread to avoid the race condition. But it did not work. Is there any problem with what I am doing?

Comment: @wmIbb synchronzied access should only be the last resort when making something thread-safe. `AtomicInteger` has much better performance

Comment: @wmIbb, Adding actual `Thread` instances to the program changes it enough that you probably should open a new SO Question.

Comment: @wmlbb as Solomon already pointed out in a comment above: you never create a thread and so you do not have to synchronize anything. But you have to ensure, that you keep the reference.